# The L deductive System in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to proof a few statements in the deductive system L, in propositional logic. The system contains 3 axioms (I, II, III below) and a few proven statements (1,2,3,4). In addition, the only inference rule is the modus ponens. In a book I found, the system differs from mine in the 3rd axiom. In the book, the 3rd axiom is (~b->~a)->((~b->a)->b) while my 3rd axiom is  (~b->~a)->(a->b). I wanted to ask, is it possible, given my axioms, statements the MP rule and the deduction theorem, to prove the 3rd axiom from the book? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need Law of Clavius. For how to derive it using your System L, see [help with some Hilbert style proofs in a propositional logic axiom system.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468356/help-with-some-hilbert-style-proofs-in-a-propositional-logic-axiom-system) Here's an answer to your question.

Theorem $\vdash(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow((\neg\beta\rightarrow\alpha)\rightarrow\beta)$

Proof:

1. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)$ (premise)
2. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\alpha)$ (premise)
3. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ (Axiom 3 in your System L)
4. $(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ (m.p. 1,3)
5. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\beta)$ (Theorem/Statement 4 in your System L, combining 2,4)
6. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow\beta$ (Law of Clavius)
7. $\beta$ (m.p. 5,6) (conclusion)
8. Therefore $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha),(\neg\beta\rightarrow\alpha)\vdash\beta$ (1,2,7,)
9. $(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\vdash(\neg\beta\rightarrow\alpha)\rightarrow\beta$ (deduction theorem)
10. $\vdash(\neg\beta\rightarrow\neg\alpha)\rightarrow((\neg\beta\rightarrow\alpha)\rightarrow\beta)$ (deduction theorem)

Answer (score -1):

You would need some sort of rule of inference for you to change deductions from I., II., or III. to a form like p -> (q -> (r -> p).  Let '{' and '}' stand in place of the third parenthesis form types, considered by their size. Let '[' and ']' stand in place of the second form types, also considered by their size.

That might require a rule of inference to change

{p -> [q -> (r -> p)]}

into

p -> [q -> (r -> p)].

That last step does not accord with the rules of formation.

That all said, something similar does *appear* to seem possible:

[image]