# Axioms of propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms, proof-theory

The book on which I'm studying logic (Mendelson) uses the following axioms:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
\text{A1)} &  P \to (Q \to P)   \\
\text{A2)} &  [P \to (Q \to R)] \to [(P \to Q) \to (P \to R)]  \\
\text{A3)} &  (\lnot P \to \lnot Q) \to [(\lnot P \to Q) \to P] \\
\end{array}$$

Other sources I’ve seen replace A3) with one of the axioms:

$$\begin{array} {rl}
\text{A3’) }& (\lnot P \to \lnot Q) \to (Q \to P) \\
\text{A3’’)}&  \lnot \lnot P \to P
\end{array}$$

Can someone give a proof of $A3$ in the systems $\{A1,A2,A3’\}$ and $\{A1,A2,A3’’\}$?

Comment: See Geoffrey Hunter, [Metalogic : An Introduction to the Metatheory of Standard First Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=oHpMtskGcv0C&pg=PA72), California Press (1971) for the system A1, A2 and A3'. See page 97 for the proof of A3'') and page 107 for the proof of A3).

Comment: Unless you are required to use them for some course, there are definitely easier, more intuitive ways to learn propositional logic. See "natural deduction" which will also ease the transition to predicate logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{A1, A2, A3''\}$ cannot establish $A3$.  Just consider when $\lnot$ is interpreted as the identity.

$\{A1, A2, A3'\}$ can establish $A3$ because it is classically complete. 
 But the actual derivation can be long and tedious. 
 For reference Bram's answer to this question: [help with some Hilbert style proofs in a propositional logic axiom system.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2468356/97045)

Comment: I didn't find Bram's answer leading to a proof of what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

$\lnot$$\lnot$P gets used only when $\lnot$P abbreviates (P$\rightarrow$$\bot$).  Thus, when used, A3'': ($\lnot$$\lnot$P$\rightarrow$P) is not the axiom, but rather (((P$\rightarrow$$\bot$)$\rightarrow$$\bot$)$\rightarrow$P) is the axiom, which is a special case of the tautology (((P$\rightarrow$Q)$\rightarrow$$\bot$)$\rightarrow$P).  That is a complete system, but you have to start with (((P$\rightarrow$$\bot$)$\rightarrow$$\bot$)$\rightarrow$P).  It doesn't occur in the first system you mentioned, since $\lnot$ is a primitive connective, nor is $\bot$ well-formed for that system.

From the theorem prover Prover9 developed by William McCune at Argonne National Laboratory; if you interpret "P" as $\vdash$, the following corresponds to a condensed detachment proof of A3 (at least if correct, I haven't hand-checked it).  Note that a correlate to $\lnot$$\lnot$P in formula 4594 gets proved here also.

```
% -------- Comments from original proof --------
% Proof 1 at 14.73 (+ 4.26) seconds.
% Length of proof is 46.
% Level of proof is 17.
% Maximum clause weight is 24.
% Given clauses 1864.

1 P((-x -> -y) -> ((-x -> y) -> x)) # label(non_clause) # label(goal).  [goal].
2 -P(x -> y) | -P(x) | P(y).  [assumption].
3 P(x -> (y -> x)).  [assumption].
4 P((x -> (y -> z)) -> ((x -> y) -> (x -> z))).  [assumption].
5 P((-x -> -y) -> (y -> x)).  [assumption].
6 -P((-c1 -> -c2) -> ((-c1 -> c2) -> c1)).  [deny(1)].
7 P(x -> (y -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,3,a)].
8 P(((x -> (y -> z)) -> (x -> y)) -> ((x -> (y -> z)) -> (x -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,4,a)].
9 P(x -> ((y -> (z -> u)) -> ((y -> z) -> (y -> u)))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,4,a)].
10 P((x -> y) -> (x -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,3,a)].
11 P(((-x -> -y) -> y) -> ((-x -> -y) -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,5,a)].
12 P(x -> ((-y -> -z) -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,5,a)].
14 P(x -> (y -> (z -> (u -> z)))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,7,a)].
17 P(x -> x).  [hyper(2,a,10,a,b,7,a)].
18 P(((x -> y) -> x) -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,17,a)].
26 P((x -> ((y -> x) -> z)) -> (x -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,8,a,b,7,a)].
44 P((x -> ((y -> (z -> y)) -> u)) -> (x -> u)).  [hyper(2,a,8,a,b,14,a)].
48 P(((x -> (y -> z)) -> (((x -> y) -> (x -> z)) -> u)) -> ((x -> (y -> z)) -> u)).  [hyper(2,a,8,a,b,9,a)].
71 P((x -> (-y -> -z)) -> (x -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,12,a)].
159 P(-x -> (x -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,26,a,b,12,a)].
160 P((x -> y) -> ((z -> x) -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,26,a,b,9,a)].
166 P(x -> (-y -> (y -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,159,a)].
197 P(((-x -> (x -> y)) -> z) -> z).  [hyper(2,a,18,a,b,166,a)].
815 P(((x -> y) -> z) -> (y -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,44,a,b,160,a)].
835 P(x -> (((y -> z) -> u) -> (z -> u))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,815,a)].
841 P(x -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,815,a,b,18,a)].
842 P(x -> ((-y -> -x) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,815,a,b,11,a)].
915 P(((x -> ((x -> y) -> y)) -> z) -> z).  [hyper(2,a,841,a,b,841,a)].
918 P((x -> y) -> (x -> ((y -> z) -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,160,a,b,841,a)].
1299 P((x -> (-y -> -x)) -> (x -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,842,a)].
3180 P((x -> (y -> z)) -> (y -> (x -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,48,a,b,835,a)].
3224 P(x -> ((((x -> y) -> y) -> z) -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,915,a,b,918,a)].
4594 P(--x -> x).  [hyper(2,a,197,a,b,1299,a)].
4644 P(--x -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,918,a,b,4594,a)].
4672 P(x -> --x).  [hyper(2,a,5,a,b,4594,a)].
4728 P((x -> y) -> (x -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,160,a,b,4672,a)].
19603 P(x -> ((x -> y) -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,4728,a)].
19609 P((x -> y) -> (--x -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,4644,a)].
20528 P(--x -> ((x -> y) -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,19609,a,b,19603,a)].
23007 P((((x -> y) -> y) -> z) -> (x -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,3224,a)].
26321 P((x -> y) -> (--x -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,20528,a)].
27746 P((x -> y) -> (-y -> -x)).  [hyper(2,a,71,a,b,26321,a)].
27754 P(x -> (-y -> -(x -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,23007,a,b,27746,a)].
28044 P((x -> -y) -> (x -> -(x -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,27754,a)].
28694 P((-x -> -y) -> ((-x -> y) -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,71,a,b,28044,a)].
28695 $F.  [resolve(28694,a,6,a)].
```