# $\neg (\neg A) \rightarrow A$ part of the axioms of propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms, provability

When talking with a mathematics teacher the other day, we discussed these axioms in the context of proving tautologies with semantic tableaux:

- $(p\to(q\to p))$
- $((p\to(q\to r))\to((p\to q)\to(p\to r)))$
- $((\lnot p\to\lnot q)\to(q\to p))$

We wondered if it was possible to show that $\neg(\neg A) \rightarrow A$ from these axioms (along with MP), but it did not seem obvious how to do so and yet this fact is not included as an axiom. Is it provable from the axioms or is this fact simply unprovable in this version of PL?

Comment: Every "true by using a truth-table method" well formed formula can be proved from these formulas and MP, including the formula you're asking about. This result is is usually proved in elementary logic classes, although typical proofs of the result are not useful for finding efficient ways to come up with derivations in specific cases. Usually you have to build up a toolbox of tricks, and maybe some preliminary results that can be used. It's been several years since I've looked at this stuff, so off-hand I don't know exactly how to get the result you want, but I'm sure others here do.

Comment: Incidentally, one of the best (possibly the best) book that I know of for learning how to find various ways of proving formulas from ["Hilbert style axioms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) is [**Propositional and Predicate Calculus: A Model of Argument**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1852339217) by Derek C. Goldrei. See also the Stack Exchange question [help with some Hilbert style proofs in a propositional logic axiom system.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468356)

Comment: $\lnot \lnot A \to A$ is not necessarily an axiom, and it is not an axiom of the above axioms system. But the above axiom systems is *sound* and *complete* for classical logic, i.e. it proves all and only tautologies. Thus, Double Negation **must** be provable with it.

Comment: It's a good thing I was a bit cautious by saying "one of the best (possibly the best)", because I just realized I overlooked what is definitely the best such book I know of, namely Eric Schecter's 2005 book [Classical and Nonclassical Logics](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691122792). This is especially embarrassing since I read and commented on parts of the manuscript for the author prior to its publication. However, I mostly recommend this for someone who is really interested in digging into the subculture of such proofs, not someone seeing them *in passing* in a foundations of math class.